# Is there any partial copy constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

Is there any way to implement copy constructor in C++ which only copies some specific members and implement move for other members.

For example, I have a class

```
class partialCopy
{
   int a;
   int largeArray[1000] ;
}
```

Now suppose using move constructor I want to keep only one copy of `largeArray` between two objects and using copy I can keep separate copy of integer a between the same two objects.

This  kind of scenario may arise while coding.

Can anyone share ideas about this?

Comment: That'd be invalid, you'd need to use a pointer, not an array for this to work.

Comment: See [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: A copy constructor is defined solely by its signature, not by what it does. You cam write your own copy constructor thst does whatever you want, from nothing to moving everything to copying to launching a nuclear attack. Of course you have ti make sure it works together with the rest of the class.

Comment: You should decide whether you want a move construtor that moves, or a copy constructor. There's no in between. If you use a `std::vector` member by value, you already have a movable type (and also copy constructible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a job for smart pointer:

```
class partialCopy {
   int a;
   std::shared_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int[]> > array;
};
```

This way you don't need to worry about these things - default generated special member functions will do the right thing for you.